# Automation using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I'm creating automation using Selenium IDE. I need to input value in a grid. When I click a 'NEW' button to input value in a grid, a pop-up window will appear. Here, you can enter the value in grid. After saving the input, pop up window will disappear. You will go back to the previous page with empty grid.

How can I save the value in a grid?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE doesn't support Java popups very well if at all. You will probably have to write the code to handle it by hand using the IWebDriver.SwitchTo() API.

The code would look something like this not knowing exactly what your dealing with.

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Window("windowName");
//do stuff to pop up
Driver.SwitchTo().Window("originalWindoName");
```